# Combine specific columns into one column in Google sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, transpose, google-query-language, textjoin

I am trying to transpose the data in the table so that Conversion Types are all stacked in one column with corresponding values. Please see the example in this sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OlQGGHnLiZFdSjbRS_2Fw7_Vhj8Z1WNZLpcZ6EWJPUA/edit?usp=sharing [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(D2:F="",, A2:A&"×"&B2:B&"×"&C2:C&"×"&D1:F1&"×"&D2:F)), 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0), "×"))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! Is there a way to add Conversion Type column so that we know what conversion is associated with the value?

Comment: this is perfect! much appreciated!